# 1999 Park Avenue makes a high -pitched squealing noise after 25 minutes of driving

Tags: noise, buick, park-avenue

Why does my 1999 Park Avenue run fine and quiet for 20 - 25 minutes of driving, but then a pulsing squeal starts? After that, a high pitched squeal. Facing the engine, the noise comes from lower right side. Any ideas? Took it to a family member and he thought it was the transmission pump. There's no burning smell or real shifting issues. He also noticed the lines about the lower front of the engine were quite hot after a short drive. There was no strong air pressure coming out of my exhaust pipe, just heat, so he felt a new muffler was needed, too. I've also sunk $1100 in it so far to get it running after sitting for a year, now this!

Comment: Generally high pitched squealing comes from old slipping front end accessory drive (FEAD) belts (generally at either the air conditioning [A/C] compressor or at the alternator. )  Does noise immediately disappear when Air Conditioning is shut off?

Comment: Thank you for responding and I apologize for the late reply. It was fixed before you responded so I hadn't checked this site. The problem was a PCV valve. When the intake manifold was replaced, they didn't replace the PCV valve. It was interesting that the mechanic who diagnosed it,  never heard the car as all the other mechanics did. I just described my problem over the phone and he immediately said it was the PCV valve. Afterwards I found out that this mechanic who fixed it is on a local radio program for helping people diagnose their car problems.  Who knew?